# iMac 21.1 -2012 ( Model 13,1 )

Tags: imac, performance, power-management

I have problems with my iMac 21.5" -2012 (13.1 model).

The machine is not starting like normal.  The fan turns on max from the begining, lasts over 6 minutes and then the system is very slow.

I changed the HDD to an SSD but it did not improve.  I put macOS Catalina, Maverick, High Sierra and the results are the same.

What can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: This could be a number of things including the [in line temp sensor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257938/119271) that’s no longer present on the SSD, a (different) faulty temp sensor to an issue with the logic board.  However, I would start off with an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) since the SMC controls power and fan speed.

Comment: tahnks, i try all this.

Comment: Hy i have different BootRoom 2.8.9.0.0 and must be 2.9.0.0.0.0 and i think this is the prolems. iMac 21,5" - late 2012 . Thanks for your answer